# How to close mongodb connections from node js using mongoose or mongodb client

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb

there are approximately 21000 connections are there for mongodb which are stale connections.

i have tried "currentOp" command to list all the connections. i was unable to close from node js using mongoose.

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Admin = mongoose.mongo.Admin;
const port = 3002
mongoose.set('debug', true)
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:22222/myapp', { 
useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
  console.log('Connection db established')
})
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.url + ' ' + new Date());
    next();
});
const Cat = mongoose.model('cats', { name: String });

db.on('open', function (err, data) {


    new Admin(db.db).command({ currentOp: 1, '$all': true }, (err, r) => {
        var connections = []
        console.log(err)
        console.log(r.inprog.length)
        r.inprog.forEach((conn) => {
            if (conn.client) {
                console.log(conn.client)
                connections.push({ thread: conn.threadId, connection: conn.connectionId, op: conn.opid })
            }
        })
        console.log(connections)
    })
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server started')
})
```

i have used "killOp" to kill connection but didn't work. and there is no "opid" for stale connections to kill or to identify

Answer (score 0):

Your mongoose connection can be closed with

```
mongoose.connection.close()
```

Make sure to put in the correct callback however, so that your database gets saved before the connection closes.

You can read more in the docs found [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-close).

Comment: actually it closes only single connection. but i want to close other connections also.

Comment: Though there may be more elegant solutions, have you considered using a for loop iterating the number of connections?

Comment: i can iterate the connections. but how can i close them. using which command or any way to close them.

Comment: Please edit the question to include what error messages/reasons for concern you are having so I can better understand what you need.

Comment: i just want to kill the connections from node js using mongoose even though those connections were established from different servers.